How to fetch first record with special condition after chosen record in Oracle query?
please help.
I have query which shows many records. I need to find way how to for example: After record with value 'A' fetch first 3 records
Thank you
CREATE TABLE "TABLETEST" 
   (
    "CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
   )


INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (1, 'valueb');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (2, 'valuec');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (3, 'valuea');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (4, 'valueD');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (5, 'valueF');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (6, 'valueY');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (7, 'valueU');
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES (8, 'valueaT');

I would like to see 3 records after record customer_id= 5


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: a single question (is it 3 records after A, like the first sentence or after customer_id=5, like the last sentence?); and the expected output for your sample data (is it inclusive or exclusive of the A/5 row?).


After record with value 'A' fetch first 3 records

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   tabletest
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY customer_id
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( {- valuea -} other{0,3})
         DEFINE valuea AS value = 'valuea'
       )

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



CUSTOMER_ID
VALUE




4
valueD


5
valueF


6
valueY



fiddle

I think you simply need Order by..fetch statement.
SEELCT *
  FROM "TABLETEST"
 WHERE "CUSTOMER_ID" > 5
 ORDER BY "CUSTOMER_ID"
 FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;


The intention is the find the first 3 items after valuea, which presumably means an ORDER BY A."ID", that is, the records that have the lowest ids that are greater than the ID of valuea, limited to 3 records.
SELECT A.*
FROM "TABLETEST" A
JOIN "TABLETEST" B
ON A."ID" > B."ID" AND B."VALUE" = 'valuea'
ORDER BY A."ID"
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;

Explanation:

we alias the relation of "TABLETEST" from whence we get the results as A
we alias the relation of "TABLETEST" that represents our infimum as B
since we want to get the records "after" B, we filter by A.ID > B.ID and of course, we specify the value of B to know what ID we need to get the following records from
of course we sort by A.ID, so we get the 3 records whose ID is the smallest from those that have a higher ID than B.ID
and we limit the result set to maximum 3 records

